# How can I open Solution from Visual Studio 2010 to 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, incompatibility

How can I open Solution from VS 2010 to VS 2013? I tried to open it in VS 2013 but one of the projects was incompatible.

[image: Project AG.BPI.Web was incompatible]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is your version / distribution of Visual Studio 2013 ?

Comment: Visual Studio Premium 2013 12.0.31101.00 Update 4.

Comment: Seems you haven't installed Web Development Tools component

Comment: I've checked and I already did